# Error with the next pointer while representing graph

Tags: c, pointers, graph

I am trying to make the adjacency list representation of a graph in c.
I am first trying to make the struct only.
However i am getting the following error everytime i use the next pointer for traversing the adjacency list

**invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct grnode')**

**incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct grnode *' from type 'struct grnode'**

I am able to understand the logic behind my code.

```
struct grnode 
{
    long long num;
    struct grnode *next;
};

struct graph 
{
    long long v;
    long long e;
    struct grnode *adj;
};

struct graph *adjlistgr()
{
    long long i,x,y;
    struct grnode *temp;
    struct graph *g = (struct graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
    if (!g) {
        printf("memory error");
        return;
    }
    // here we scanf  the num of vertices and edges
    scanf("%lld %lld", &g->v, &g->e);
    g->adj = malloc(g->v*sizeof(struct grnode*));
    for (i = 0; i < g->v; i++)
    {           
        g->adj[i].num = i;
        g->adj[i]->next = g->adj[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < g->e;i++)
    {   // now we scan the edges
        scanf("%lld %lld", &x, &y);
        temp = (struct grnode*)malloc( sizeof( struct grnode*));
        temp->num = y;
        temp->next = g->adj[x];
        g->adj[x]->next = temp;
        temp = (struct grnode*)malloc( sizeof( struct grnode*));
        temp->num = y;
        temp->next = g->adj[y];
        g->adj[y]->next = temp;
    }
    return g;
}
```

Comment: When you malloc, you reserve space for `v` pointers only, but you want to reserve space for `v` structs. In general, follow the pattern `Something *s = malloc(count * sizeof(*s))`. In other words, the handle for your dynamic array is a pointer, the array data are not.

Comment: Side note: After you fix your compilation errors, change `sizeof(struct grnode*)` to `sizeof(struct grnode)`.  This is the next problem you'll run into, and it will happen during runtime, which will make it harder for you to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g->adj[i]->next
```

should be

```
g->adj[i].next
```

`adj[i]` is a pointer already so no need to use the `->` operator. Fix the same thing everywhere.

and

```
g->adj = malloc(g->v*sizeof(struct grnode*));
```

should be

```
g->adj = malloc((g->v)*sizeof(struct grnode));
```

Allocate memory for your structure which is given by `sizeof(struct grnode)`

For your understanding:

```
struct b
{
   int b;
};

struct a
{
   int a;
   struct b *ptr;
};

int main()
{
   struct a *p = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
   p->a = 10;
   p->ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct b) * 2);
   /* Now you have a pointer `ptr` which can hold 2 struct b */
   /* So the access should be like */

   p->ptr[0].b = 20; /* ptr[0] = *(ptr +0)  */ 
   p->ptr[1].b = 30; /* ptr[1] = *(ptr + 1) */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it shows request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union

Comment: @user3692108 Please consider the changes shown. Your access needs to change

Comment: `g->adj[i]` is struct, so you should access its field with the `.` operator, as Gopi said. That also means that you cannot assign its value to `x->next`; you'll need a pointer here: `g->adj[i].next = &g->adj[i]`

Comment: it still shows incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct grnode *' from type 'struct grnode'

Comment: Thanks for the help  i used . and removed * and added the address everywhere          now still it shows                                   error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
   temp.next = &g->adj[x];
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   g->adj[y].next = &temp;

Comment: Thanks  my problem has been solved how do i close this thread i am a newbie